# What is the efficient way to create schema for a dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark

I am new to spark and I saw that there are two ways to create a data frame's schema.
I have an RDD: empRDD with data(split by ",")

```
+---+-------+------+-----+
|  1|   Mark|  1000|   HR|
|  2|  Peter|  1200|SALES|
|  3|  Henry|  1500|   HR|
|  4|   Adam|  2000|   IT|
|  5|  Steve|  2500|   IT|
|  6|  Brian|  2700|   IT|
|  7|Michael|  3000|   HR|
|  8|  Steve| 10000|SALES|
|  9|  Peter|  7000|   HR|
| 10|    Dan|  6000|   BS|
+---+-------+------+-----+

val empFile = sc.textFile("emp")
val empData = empFile.map(e => e.split(","))
```

First way to create schema is using a case class:

```
case class employee(id:Int, name:String, salary:Int, dept:String)
val empRDD = empData.map(e => employee(e(0).toInt, e(1), e(2).toInt, e(3)))
val empDF = empRDD.toDF()
```

Second way is using StructType:

```
    val empSchema = StructType(Array(StructField("id", IntegerType, true),
                    StructField("name", StringType, true), 
                    StructField("salary", IntegerType, true), 
                    StructField("dept", StringType, true)))
    val empRDD = empdata.map(e => Row(e(0).toInt, e(1), e(2).toInt, e(3)))
    val empDF  = sqlContext.createDataFrame(empRDD, empSchema)
```

Personally I prefer to code using StructType. But I don't know which way is recommended in the actual industry projects. Could anyone let me know the preferred way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [spark-csv](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv) library to read a `csv` files, This library have lots of `options` as per our requirement.

You can read a csv file as

```
val df = sqlContext.read
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .option("header", "true") // Use first line of all files as header
    .option("inferSchema", "true") // Automatically infer data types
    .load("data.csv")
```

However you can also provide schema manually.

I think the best way is to read a `csv` with `spark-csv` as a `dataset` as

```
val cities = spark.read
  .option("header", "true")
  .csv(location)
  .as[employee]
```

Read the advantage of dataset over rdd and dataframe [here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/apache-spark-rdd-vs-dataframe-dataset-chandan-prakash).

You can also generate the schema from case class if you have it already.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders
val empSchema = Encoders.product[Employee].schema
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I understood the concept you proposed but I don't have a schema in my input file. I want to create schema for the existing data.

Comment: Than you can add schema as  .schema(empSchema)

Comment: Yes. 
I was referring on how to create "empschema". Is the preferred way using a case class or by StructType ?

Comment: Since you already have a case class, the better would be to generate the schema with your case class

Comment: There is no case class limit with scala 2.11 so you can accept this an an answer.

Answer (score 1):

In the case when you are creating your RDD's from a CSV file(or any delimited file) you can infer schema automatically as @Shankar Koirala mentioned.

In case you are creating your RDD's from a different source then:

A. When you have less number of fields(less than 22) you can create it using case classes.

B. When you have more than 22 fields you need to create schema programmatically

[Link to Spark Programming Guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#programmatically-specifying-the-schema)

Comment: can't we create a case class with more than 22 fields ?

Answer (score 0):

If your input file is delimited file, you can use databrick's spark-csv library.

Use this way:

```
// For spark < 2.0
DataFrame df = sqlContext.read()
            .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
            .option("header", "true")
            .option("nullValue", "")
            .load("./data.csv");
df.show();
```

For spark 2.0;

```
DataFrame df = sqlContext.read()
            .format("csv")
            .option("header", "true")
            .option("nullValue", "")
            .load("./data.csv");
df.show();
```

There are lots of customization possible using `option` in the command.
Such as:

1. `.option("inferSchema", "true")` to infer data types of each column automatically.
2. `.option("codec", "org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec")` to define compression codec
3. `.option("delimiter", ",")` to specify delimiter as `','`

Databrick's spark-csv library is ported in to spark 2.0.

Using this library will give you freedom from the difficulties parsing various use cases of delimited files.

Refer: `https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv`